# PHP documentation clarification: Closure::bindTo

Tags: php, closures

> This function will ensure that for a non-static closure, having a
>   bound instance **will imply being scoped and vice-versa**.

WHAT? i read it 100 times and i still don't understand it.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: what is the meaning of "will imply being scoped and vice-versa"?

Answer (score 0):

`bindTo` set's the `$this` variable, which allows you to rebind a closure to a different instance.  Example:

```
<?php

// by default, in global scope $this is null
$cl = function() {
    return isset($this) && $this instanceof \DateTime ? $this->format(\DateTime::ISO8601) : 'null';
};

printf("%s\n", $cl()); // prints 'null'

// bind a new instance of this \Closure to an instance of \DateTime
$b = new \DateTime();
$cl = $cl->bindTo($b);

printf('%s\n', $cl()); // prints current date
```

Comment: they both print `null` and you didn't use `bindTo`. and why did you use `ReflectionClass`? id didn't understand you answer

Answer (score 0):

In short it just means you can use $this in a closure and it will refer to the instance (if there is any) wihout having to reassign $this to $me and using it via use ()...

(from the docs)

```
<?php

class A {
    function __construct($val) {
        $this->val = $val;
    }
    function getClosure() {
        //returns closure bound to this object and scope
        return function() { return $this->val; };
    }
}

$ob1 = new A(1);
$ob2 = new A(2);

$cl = $ob1->getClosure(); // $this in the closure will be $ob1
echo $cl(), "\n"; // thus printing 1
$cl = $cl->bindTo($ob2);  // $this in the closure will be changed (re-binded) to $ob2
echo $cl(), "\n"; // thus printing 2
?>
```